# Title of plot same as filename in matplotlib

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, plot, titlebar

I want to print the title of the plot, as the file name it is plotting. so whatever files it plots it should the title as 'Raman Spectra of filename'.
I am trying this way but doesn't work

```
   def OnPlot(self, event):
    cursor= self.conn.execute("SELECT FILE_NAME FROM MOLECULE where MOL_NUMBER==?", (self.plot_list[0],))
    files = cursor.fetchall()
    #print files[0][0]
    tf = open(files[0][0],'r+')
d = tf.readlines()
tf.seek(0)
for line in d:
         s=re.search(r'[a-zA-Z]',line)
         if s:
             tf.write('#'+line)
         else:
             tf.write(line)
    tf.truncate()
    tf.close()
    plt.plotfile(str(files[0][0]), delimiter=' ',comments = '#', cols=(0, 1), 
               names=('Raman Shift ($\mathregular{Cm^{-1}}$)', 'Intensity (arb. units)'), ) 
    plt.title('Raman Spectra of "files"')
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is a little bit fuzzy:) Something like

```
plt.title('Raman Spectra of {}'.format(files[0][0]))
```

?